# Version Number on Word document in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, sharepoint-online

I am trying to insert the version number stored in SharePoint Online into my Word document - I've done the following thus far:

- Activated the Library and Folder Based Retention Site Collection feature
- Checked "Enable Labels" in the Information Management Policy Settings for the Document Content Type, and entered "{Version}" into the Label format field
- Created a Word document in my library
- Opened the document in Word, and inserted a Quick Part (Document Property > Label)

What shows up on the document is {_UIVersionString}, not the actual version number.  Not sure what's going on - it seems so close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my test, I cannot reproduce your problem.

I can display the correct version number in the document. Below is a screenshot of my test:

[image]

[image]

[image]

This may be caused by the cache, I suggest you to clean up the cache of the SharePoint page and Office first.

You can provide your detailed screenshots, which can help us solve the problem better.

Comment: I had to close all of my open Word documents, and then it started working.  Your comment about clearing the cache helped me - so for anyone who finds this, just make sure you close all Documents before you put the label in a document.